# Can't connect to VNC server via OpenVPN

Tags: debian, vpn, firewall, openvpn, vnc

I've got the problem with connecting via VNC to remote computer. Connection goes through OpenVPN and I'm routing 5900 port to localhost..

```
ssh -p(port) -L5900:vpn adress of machine:5900 user@server.example
```

and then viewing by Remmina at my computer but gives me

```
VNC server closed connection
```

I can ping machine from server via VPN but when i telnet port 5900 it gaves me this:

```
Trying 10.36.1.5...
Connected to 10.36.1.5.
Escape character is '^]'.
RFB 003.008
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

and disconnect. Machine is listening on 5900 and got installed x11vpn...

Btw: if i connect to machine by another OpenVPN server VNC works..

Running Debian Jessie

Any advices? Thank you so much

Comment: anyone? can help me?